# How to free memory occupied by a Tree, C?

Tags: c, tree, free

I'm currently dealing with a generic Tree with this structure:

```
typedef struct NODE {

    //node's keys
    unsigned short *transboard;
    int depth;
    unsigned int i; 
    unsigned int j;
    int player;
    int value;


    struct NODE *leftchild; //points to the first child from the left
    struct NODE *rightbrothers; //linked list of brothers from the current node

}NODE;

static NODE *GameTree = NULL;
```

While the function that allocates the different nodes is (don't bother too much at the keys' values, basically allocates the children-nodes. If there aren't any the new child goes to leftchild, otherwise it goes at the end of the list "node->leftchild->rightbrothers"):

```
static int AllocateChildren(NODE **T, int depth, unsigned int i, unsigned int j, int player, unsigned short *transboard) {
NODE *tmp = NULL;

if ((*T)->leftchild == NULL) {
    if(  (tmp = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE))  )== NULL) return 0;
    else {
        tmp->i = i;
        tmp->j = j;
        tmp->depth = depth;
        (player == MAX ) ? (tmp->value = 2 ): (tmp->value = -2);
        tmp->player = player;
        tmp->transboard = transboard;

        tmp->leftchild = NULL;
        tmp->rightbrothers = NULL;

        (*T)->leftchild = tmp;
    }
}

else {
    NODE *scorri = (*T)->leftchild;
    while (scorri->rightbrothers != NULL)
        scorri = scorri->rightbrothers;

    if( ( tmp = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE)) )== NULL) return 0;
    else {
        tmp->i = i;
        tmp->j = j;
        tmp->depth = depth;
        (player == MAX) ? (tmp->value = 2) : (tmp->value = -2);
        tmp->player = player;
        tmp->transboard = transboard;

        tmp->leftchild = NULL;
        tmp->rightbrothers = NULL;
    }
    scorri->rightbrothers = tmp;


}

return 1;

}
```

I need to come up with a function, possibly recursive, that deallocates the whole tree, so far I've come up with this:

```
 void DeleteTree(NODE **T) {

 if((*T) != NULL) {
    NODE *tmp;
    for(tmp = (*T)->children; tmp->brother != NULL; tmp = tmp->brother) {
        DeleteTree(&tmp);
    }

    free(*T);

 }
}
```

But it doesn't seem working, it doesn't even deallocate a single node of memory.
Any ideas of where I am being wrong or how can it be implemented?
P.s. I've gotten the idea of the recursive function from this pseudocode from my teacher. However I'm not sure I've translated it correctly in C with my kind of Tree.
Pseudocode:

```
1: function DeleteTree(T)
2:    if T != NULL then
3:       for c ∈ Children(T) do
4:          DeleteTree(c)
5:       end for
6:       Delete(T)
7:    end if
8: end function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just realized my BIG mistake in the code and I'll just answer myself since no one had found the answer.

The error lies in this piece of code:

```
for(tmp = (*T)->children; tmp->brother != NULL; tmp = tmp->brother) {
    DeleteTree(&tmp);
}
```

First of all Ami Tavory was right about the for condition, i need to continue as long as tmp != NULL
Basically it won't just work because after the DeleteTree(&tmp), I can no longer access the memory in tmp because *it's obviously deleted*, so after the first cycle of for ends I can't do tmp = tmp->rightbrother to move on the next node to delete because tmp->rightbrother no longer exists as I just deleted it.
In order to fix it I just needed to save the tmp->brother somewhere else:

```
void DeleteTree(NODE **T) {

   if((*T) != NULL) {
       NODE *tmp, *deletenode, *nextbrother;

       for(tmp = (*T)->children; tmp != NULL; tmp = nextbrother) {
           nextbrother = tmp->rightbrother;
           DeleteTree(&tmp);

       }

   canc = (*T);
   free(*T);
   (*T) = NULL;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I like doing if I'm allocating lots of tree nodes, that are going to go away at the same time, is to allocate them in 'batches'. I `malloc` then as an array of nodes and dole them out from a special `nodealloc` function after saving a pointer to the array (in a function like below). To drop the tree I just make sure I'm not keeping any references and then call the free routine (also like below).

This can also reduce the amount of RAM you allocate if you're lucky (or very smart) with your initial `malloc` or can trust `realloc` not to move the block when you shrink it.

```
struct freecell { struct freecell * next; void * memp; } * saved_pointers = 0;

static void
save_ptr_for_free(void * memp)
{
    struct freecell * n = malloc(sizeof*n);
    if (!n) {perror("malloc"); return; }
    n->next = saved_pointers;
    n->memp = memp;
    saved_pointers = n;
}

static void
free_saved_memory(void)
{
    while(saved_pointers) {
        struct freecell * n = saved_pointers;
        saved_pointers = saved_pointers->next;
        free(n->memp);
        free(n);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness I want to add my version of DeleteTree

```
void DeleteTree(NODE *T) {
  if(T != NULL) {
    DeleteTree(T->rightbrothers);
    DeleteTree(T->leftchild);
    free(T);
  }
}
```

I think it is much less obscure and much easier to read. Basically it solves the issue in DeleteTree but through eliminating the loop.

Since we free the nodes recursively we might as well do the whole process recursively.